# SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER converting XLS to TXT

Tags: ssis, oledb, redistributable, aceoledb, access-database-engine

I started a new job with a brand new laptop and vanilla environment.

I have installed Visual Studio and I'm trying to convert a XLS file to TXT. This is my Control Flow:

[image]

And this is my Data Flow:

[image]

When I run the package I incur in the notorious error:

```
SSIS package "C:\Users\fmv\source\repos\XtoT\XtoT\Package.dtsx" starting.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Error: 0xC0209303 at Package, Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager 2": The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered. If the 64-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 32-bit mode. Error code: 0x00000000.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".
Error: 0xC001002B at Package, Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager 2": The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=219816
Error: 0xC020801C at Data Flow Task, Excel Source [2]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager 2" failed with error code 0xC0209303.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
Error: 0xC0047017 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Excel Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
Error: 0xC004700C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: One or more component failed validation.
Error: 0xC0024107 at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.
SSIS package "C:\Users\fmv\source\repos\XtoT\XtoT\Package.dtsx" finished: Failure.
The program '[18396] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I tried to switch the connector to `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0` but the error is the same.

So I read some guide and they mostly suggest to download Microsoft Access Database Engine. So I download the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920) and when I run the 32-bit it says:

*You cannnot install the 32-bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 because you currently have 64-bit Office products installed. If you want to install 32-bit Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016, you will first need to remove the 64-bit installation of Office products. After uninstalling the following product(s), rerun setup in order to install 32-bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016: Office 16 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component 64-bit Registration*

[image]

So I tried with the 64-bit instead and the computer says:

*You cannnot install the 64-bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 because you currently have 32-bit Office products installed. If you want to install 64-bit Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016, you will first need to remove the 32-bit installation of Office products. After uninstalling the following product(s), rerun setup in order to install 64-bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016: Microsoft Access database engine 2010 (English), Office 16 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component*

[image]

...so, which is which? I currently have `Microsoft® Outlook ® for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.01380120442) 32-bit`.

So I found anotherguide here on StackOverflow that said that the right version I need is [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255). And it was true, at least I was able to install the 32-bit.

But apart from that I'm still experiencing the problem even if I don't have red dots on the control Flow or on the Data Flow.

Any idea about how to try next?

Comment: Visual Studio works in 32bit (for now), so you'll need to use the 32bit version.  You can force this to install by opening a command prompt as an admin and running it with the quiet switch `\AccessDatabaseEngine.exe /quiet`

Comment: I will try tomorrow. 2016 or 2010?

Comment: I would use the latest version

Comment: Not sure why but it keeps erroring